# APNS aps-environement-Entitlement for Testflight Version / Production build of App

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications, testflight

Something strange is happening currently in one of the apps i'm developing.

While developing the APNS Pushtoken could be obtained properly. As soon as I pushed the app for testflight internal testing it doesn't work anymore.

The well-known error is throwed: 'APNS Push token - No valid aps-environement-entitlement whatever could be found'

I usually solved this error through refreshing all the mobile provisioning profiles in XCode, but this doesn't work in that case.

[image]

The App ID is configured properly for push notifications production and development.

[image]

Any Ideas? Would really be glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the provisioning profile was created before adding the Push Notifications to the App ID. Creating a new Provisioning Profile and download it through XCode solved it.